# Does elm share objects or duplicate them?

Tags: elm

I'm working on a e-commerce website with a front-end in Elm and I am wondering if objects are shared or duplicated. I'm pretty sure of the answer but I just want to make sure.

Basically, I have a `ProductVariant` containing some `Colour`. At the moment `ProductVariant` as a field `colour_ids : List ColourId` (which is what I got from the json) but I am thinking replacing the id with the colour itself : `colours : List Colour` . I can do that when I decode the JSON and then it's done, I don't need to lookup coulours in the `colours` dictionary. Am I correct to assume that each `Colour` will be shared between different variant or each colour will be duplicated, thus taking more memory.

Comment: I would also _guess_ that it will duplicate the data. This is of course implementation details and could change. But since all data is immutable, there isn't really a reason why it couldn't be shared internally. You can make a small test Elm program and see what the compiled JS output looks like. If you go that far, post your info here for others to know about the details.

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple program to see the compiled JS output. With Elm code

```
type alias Color = { red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int }

black: Color
black = { red = 255, green = 255, blue = 255 }

white: Color
white = { red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0 }

red: Color
red = { red = 255, green = 0, blue = 0 }

colors: List Color
colors =
  [
    black,
    white,
    red,
    { red = 123, green = 234, blue = 11 },
    black,
    { red = 123, green = 234, blue = 11 },
    red,
    { red = 123, green = 234, blue = 11 }
  ]
```

The output JS code contains

```
var author$project$SharedData$colors = _List_fromArray(
    [
        author$project$SharedData$black,
        author$project$SharedData$white,
        author$project$SharedData$red,
        {blue: 11, green: 234, red: 123},
        author$project$SharedData$black,
        {blue: 11, green: 234, red: 123},
        author$project$SharedData$red,
        {blue: 11, green: 234, red: 123}
    ]);
```

This shows that the compiler is able to reuse the pre-defined colors black, white and red, but when creating a new record even with the exact same data, there'll always be a duplication.

I don't know how your data is organized, but for the above example case, instead of trying to optimize the data structure, I would simply store the colors as hex code strings.

I'm not 100% sure how JS engines handle strings, but on many other platforms there's only one instance in heap of a single string. For the above toy app this would mean to use `"7BEA0B"` instead of `{ red: 123, green: 234, blue: 11 }`

Comment: That's really helpful. In my case  color is actual an entity on its own (with a name, url, even images etc ...) so storing colours as a string is not an option. I was more thinking of does duplicate occurs when a object is fetch from a dictionary then pass through a function and finally added somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

following @kaskelotti advices I made small program fetching the same item twice from a dictionary and checked using the JS debugger if data where shared.

```
import Html exposing (text,div)

import Dict
a = {t= "My name is a"}
b = {t= "My name is B"}
d = Dict.fromList [("a", a), ("b", b)]

mytest = List.filterMap (\key -> Dict.get key d) ["a", "b", "a"]

main = 
    let x = mytest
       (y, z)=  case x of
                 [a1,_,a2] -> (a1,a2)
                 _ -> (a,b)

    in div [] (List.map (\o -> text o.t) mytest)
```

By setting a breakpoint in `main` I could check that `y` and`z` are actually the same (`y === z` is true). Also modify `y.t` modifies `z.t`.